# Is there a way to check if a ComboBox has any items in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

Is there a way to check if a `ComboBox` has any items in it or whether it is empty? I have an array of `ComboBox`es and I need to go through each of them, if there are no items in the `ComboBox`, then I must hide it. This following code doesn't seem to work:

```
for (ComboBox cmb : comboBoxes) {
    if (cmb.getItems().isEmpty()) {
        cmb.hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe getItems().size () < 1

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to do the trick along with cmb.setVisible(false);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `.getItems()` method returns an `ObservableList<T>` so you can just check its `.size()`.  This will tell you if it's empty.

```
for (ComboBox cmb : comboBoxes) {
  if (cmb.getItems().size() <= 0) { // or cmb.getItems().isEmpty()
      cmb.setVisible(false); }
}
```

If the `ComboBox` is populated by a `List` of its own, you could also just check if the list is empty with the same `.size()` call.

Answer (score 4):

The code for checking, if the `ComboBox` has no items is correct, you code for hiding the `ComboBox`es is incorrect however.

`ComboBox.hide` only closes the popup showing the items, if it's open. It does not hide the `ComboBox`. To hide the `ComboBox`, you need to set the visibility:

```
for (ComboBox cmb : comboBoxes) {
    if (cmb.getItems().isEmpty()) {
        cmb.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to call a method to hide the `ComboBox`es, you can bind the [`visibleProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#visibleProperty--) of the `ComboBox`es to their own [`itemsProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#itemsProperty--) with a custom binding:

```
List<ComboBox<String>> comboBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
    ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>();
    combo.visibleProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> !combo.getItems().isEmpty(),
        combo.itemsProperty().get()));
    comboBoxes.add(combo);
}
```

The advantage is, that you don't have to call any methods to hide your `ComboBox`es, because the binding is evaluated automatically, therefore no one can see your empty combos.